# How to stop Application.OnTime Overlapping Itself?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m writing a VBA code that notifies me when it’s time to leave the office.

It gets the time to prompt me from the workbook sheet, but the value changes as I update the time I’ve arrived at work, how long the lunch was, etc.

I created a code that is triggered when some cells change, the problem is that the cells change multiple times before it gets to the actual time I should leave. So instead of getting one notification I get multiple of them.

Basically the same macro is running multiple times. When I change a cell, it should actually stop this macro if it's running, and relaunch my macro.

I’ve googled it and nothing helped.

```
Sub NotifyMe()
'Declare Variables
    Dim notificationStr, leaveStr As String
    Dim notificationTime As Date
    Dim leaveTime As Date

'Defines now Time
    h = Hour(Now())
    m = Minute(Now())
    s = Second(Now())
    nowtime = TimeSerial(h, m, s)
'Defines the time it will prompt me
    leaveTime = Cells(5, 2).Value
    notificationTime = Cells(5, 2).Value - Cells(6, 2).Value
'Creates a string to be presented in the MsgBox
    notificationStr = Format(notificationTime, "Short Time")
    leaveStr = Format(leaveTime, "Short Time")
    nowStr = Format(nowtime, "short time")
' If it's passed the time, it will notify me
    If nowtime >= notificationTime Then
        Beep
        a = MsgBox("Agora sao " & nowStr & ". E voce tem que sair as " & leaveStr, vbExclamation, "Nao se Atase!")
    Else
        'Schedules the macro to run at the notificationTime
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=notificationTime, Procedure:="NotifyMe", Schedule:=True
    End If

End Sub

'Runs NotifyMe everytime a keycell is changed
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim keyCells As Range
    Set keyCells = Range("B1:B8")

    If Not Application.Intersect(keyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        NotifyMe
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can end scheduled `Application.OnTime` events using this pattern:

```
Public notificationTime As Date

Application.OnTime notificationTime, "NotifyMe", Schedule:=False
```

By doing `notificationTime` a public variable, you can use it to reference exactly the same procedure scheduled before and close the procedure with `Schedule:=False`.

Please try this, normally I'm the last person to use On Error Resume Next, but I think it's the easiest and most reliable way in this case.

```
Option Explicit
Public notificationTime As Date

Sub NotifyMe()
'Declare Variables
    Dim notificationStr, leaveStr As String, a As String
    Dim nowtime As Date, leaveTime As Date, nowStr As Date
    Dim h As Long, m As Long, s As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime notificationTime, "NotifyMe", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0

'Defines now Time
    h = Hour(Now())
    m = Minute(Now())
    s = Second(Now())
    nowtime = TimeSerial(h, m, s)
'Defines the time it will prompt me
    leaveTime = Cells(5, 2).Value
    notificationTime = Cells(5, 2).Value - Cells(6, 2).Value
'Creates a string to be presented in the MsgBox
    notificationStr = Format(notificationTime, "Short Time")
    leaveStr = Format(leaveTime, "Short Time")
    nowStr = Format(nowtime, "Short Time")
' If it's passed the time, it will notify me
    If nowtime >= notificationTime Then
        Beep
        a = MsgBox("Agora sao " & nowStr & ". E voce tem que sair as " & leaveStr, vbExclamation, "Nao se Atase!")
    Else
        'Schedules the macro to run at the notificationTime
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=notificationTime, Procedure:="NotifyMe", Schedule:=True
    End If

End Sub
```

Also on exiting this Excel workbook, if task is scheduled, but other Excel workbook is open, the workbook will be open automatically on scheduled time and execute the code, unless the task is also killed on closing the workbook. The code below should be put in `ThisWorkbook` object's code if you want to prevent it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime notificationTime, "NotifyMe", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Ryszard, thaks for the answer. It is not working though. This is what it looks like:

    Public notificationTime As Date
    Sub NotifyMe()

    'Declare Variables
        Dim notificationStr, leaveStr As String
        Dim leaveTime As Date
        Dim h, m, s As Integer
    
        'End previous instances of this macro
        Application.OnTime notificationTime, "NotifyMe", Schedule:=False
... Continues just like the code above

Comment: It wont even compile the program. It returns an error at the line "Application.OnTime notificationTime, "NotifyMe", Schedule:=False"

Comment: I have posted full code, I also recommend to always use Option Explicit, so that there are no errors connected to variable type.

Comment: One more question: What exactly is "On Error GoTo 0" doing in that code?

Comment: Good question, it basically cancels `On Error Resume Next` at the moment it is used. After `On Error GoTo 0`, all errors will be reported normally. By doing this, all unexpected errors will be easy to track. With `On Error Resume Next` macro would just continue without reporting any error. So in this macro `On Error Resume Next` is active only in one line, where error is sometimes expected (no tasks scheduled).

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.EnableEvents   = false at the start 
And Application.EnableEvents = true at the end of the macro.
It will suppress further events while you are in a macro and enables them once you are done.